# How to make history of previous props | states in a certain component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know how to retain previous states or props in a certain component. We may declare a global variable and store all the states or props. It works. But some experts criticize the way using global variables in React. How can I solve this out?

Comment: Could you give some context? The first thing that springs to mind is that maybe the state should be an _array_, where each time there's an update it looks like `[...previousValue, { ...previousValue[previousValue.length - 1], /* update */ }]`?